# count elements in xml using objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, count

I've got an XML file and I need to count how many times the  element appears in it using Objective-C. How should I do this?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<residents>
    <resident id="1">
        <name>
            <first>David</first>
            <last>Dollar</last>
        </name>
    </resident>

    <resident id="2">
        <name>
            <first>Michael</first>
            <last>Nipp</last>
        </name>
    </resident>
```

etc...

Comment: What xml reader are you using?

Comment: I'm using NSXMLParser. I need the code to count the number of times the <resident> element appears.

Comment: Sorry i have never really worked with NSXMLParser as i found TBXML much easier to understand and to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I would set your class as the delegate of the parser, then this class will receive parse events such as `parser:didStartElement:`, `parser:foundCharacters:` and `parser:didEndElement:`.

```
self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
[self.parser setDelegate:self]; 
[self.parser parse];
```

I would create a count variable in your parser delegate. Anytime an element is found, the `didStartElement:` function is called on the parser delegate. Check if it's the "resident" element and increment the count if so.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"resident"]) {

        self.count += 1; 

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very new at this and this may be a silly question but.... where do I put the code?  ie. self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]...

Comment: You could put the code in your view controller, the initialization could happen in the viewDidLoad method.